# Dagger 2 : compilation fail sometimes

Tags: android, dagger-2

after many hours getting headaches... i'm resigned to ask you guys ^^

got two simple Dagger 2 components but both of them doesn't compile. But sometimes (i don't understand why) it does ...
this is really annoying.

So i think i should miss something, here is the error :

Error:(18, 17) error: ....InstanceContextService cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
home.HomeActivity.mInstanceContextService
[injected field of type: ....services.InstanceContextService mInstanceContextService]

So my compoments is like this :

```
@Component(modules = {InstanceContextModule.class})
@Singleton
public interface InstanceContextComponent {

    @Singleton
    void inject(HomeActivity activity);
    }
```

My module :

```
@Module
public class InstanceContextModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public InstanceContextService provideInstanceContext() {
        return new FileInstanceService();
    }
}
```

and my config in gradle is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
//    compileOptions.incremental = false

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kayentis.ediary"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs = [
                    'src/main/res',
                    'src/main/res-main',
                    'src/main/res-message',
                    'src/main/res-account'
            ]
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.1'
    //compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.6.1'

    //Dagger 2
//    apt  'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.3'
//    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.3'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.2'
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
    //Retrofit 2.0
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
    //RxJava
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
    //ButterKnife
//    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
}
```

I'm looking everywhere but i think i miss something...
Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: for the comment, i still have the error by removing one component but i can go to the generated class. So the class is generated but it seems the compilation don't see it in javaC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Solution.

Had two component with @singleton scoped modules, so this can't work. Now it's building successfull.

Comment: if you use field injection, your component has to be able to resolve all dependencies that you want to inject (from its modules).